# Converting LaTeX pmatrix command to amsmath pmatrix environment using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have an old LaTeX document (with a lot of formatting commands) that I want to convert to the more modern LaTeX (I want to do the update for several reasons, not the least of which is to reduce the coupling between content and formatting).  At any rate, the document has a lot of calls to the deprecated command `\pmatrix{ .... }` which I would like to replace with the new amsmath command `\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}`.  I have been trying to use `sed` to do this conversion but I have never used it before and I am having trouble.

Here is a MWE
LaTeX input string

```
\pmatrix{0&0\cr \frac{1}{2}&0\cr 0&0\cr}\pmatrix{1&1\cr 1&1\cr 1&1\cr}
```

with the expected output

```
\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ \frac{1}{2}&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}
```

The commands that I have been trying to use are variants of the following

```
sed 's/\\pmatrix{\(.*\cr[ ]*\)}/\\begin{pmatrix}\1 \\end{pmatrix}/g' <$WORKING_FILE >$OUTPUT_FILE
```

but the closest output that I have been able to achieve is

```
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is related to having two calls to `pmatrix` side by side, but I am not sure how to modify the regex to make this work.

I have searched google, but being so new to regex, I just got confused by all of the variations out there and which to use, and how to properly format such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work for you:

```
sed -re 's/(\\pmatrix)\{([^}]*)}/\\begin{pmatrix}\2\\end{pmatrix}/g' -e 's/\\cr/\\\\/g' -e 's/\\\\\\end/\\end/g' inputfile
```

This works by:

- substituting `\pmatrix{...}` with `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}
- substituting `\cr` with `\\`
- handling `\\\end` to make it `\end`

EDIT: As per your update, you might be better off splitting the relevant parts using `grep` before piping to `sed`:

```
grep -oP '\\pmatrix.*?\\cr}' inputfile | sed -re 's/\\pmatrix\{(.*)}/\\begin{pmatrix}\1\\end{pmatrix}/g;s/\\cr/\\\\/g;s/\\\\\\end/\\end/g'
```

Comment: That is really close but there are some `}` before the final `\\}`.  I have edited the question to reflect this.  I think the solution requires that I somehow check for a not repeated sequence of characters `\\}` instead of just `}` but I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: @slbass The edit above might work for you.  If you want the output to be present on the same line, pipe the output to `paste -sd ' '`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\\cr/\n/g;s/\\(pmatrix)\{([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n\}/\\begin{\1}\2\\\\ \3\\\\ \4\\end{\1}/g;s/\n/\\cr/g' file
```

Convert `\\cr` to newlines. Do a global substitution command. Then convert those newlines left back to `\\cr`'s.